# setTimeout in "change" event handler but only for distinct caller

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, handler

Basically what I need to do is `alert()` the passed in value after 3 seconds, clearing any previous timeouts, but per per caller.  I could do this by creating a change event handler for all 3 input boxes, but wanted to try to accomplish this with just one handler.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt1" value="0" />
    <button class="btn" id="btn1">btn1</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt2" value="0" /> 
    <button class="btn" id="btn2">btn2</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt3" value="0" /> 
    <button class="btn" id="btn3">btn3</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var currnum = $(this).closest(".container").find('input[id*="txt"]').val();
    var newnum = parseFloat(currnum) + 1;
    $(this).closest(".container").find('input[id*="txt"]').val(newnum).trigger("change");
});

var timer;
$('.brown').bind("change", function () {
    //clear all current timeouts
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var s = $(this).val();
    //pause for 3 seconds before alert
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        alert(s);
    }, 3000);
});
```

So the desired results would be if I click `btn1` twice then `btn2` once then `btn3` three times the alerts would indicate `2` then `1` then `3`.  The value the handler should alert is the last value of the appropriate input when the 3 seconds is up.  In my case, I simply just get one alert (val 3) because it it clearing all other timers.  I could accomplish this using 3 different change handlers, one for each input, but is this something that can be done with one handler? I appreciate the feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with an object which holds a timer for each element. In that case you are able to clear only the timer of the current element and you can distinguish between the different timers for the different elements.

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var currnum = $(this).closest(".container").find('input[id*="txt"]').val();
    var newnum = parseFloat(currnum) + 1;
    $(this).closest(".container").find('input[id*="txt"]').val(newnum).trigger("change");
});

var timers = {};
$('.brown').bind("change", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //clear the current timer
    clearTimeout(timers[id]);
    var s = $(this).val();
    //pause for 3 seconds before alert
    timers[id] = setTimeout(function () {
        alert(s);
    }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt1" value="0" />
    <button class="btn" id="btn1">btn1</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt2" value="0" /> 
    <button class="btn" id="btn2">btn2</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt3" value="0" /> 
    <button class="btn" id="btn3">btn3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you change timer to array , your code will run correctly for example:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt1" value="0" />
    <button class="btn" id="btn1">btn1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt2" value="0" />
    <button class="btn" id="btn2">btn2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="brown" readonly="readonly" id="txt3" value="0" />
    <button class="btn" id="btn3">btn3</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(".btn").on("click", function() {
      var currnum =
        $(this).closest(".container").find('input[id*="txt"]').val();
      var newnum = parseFloat(currnum) + 1;
      $(this).closest(".container").find('input[id*="txt"]').val(newnum).trigger("change");
    });
    var timer = [];
    timer.length = $(".brown").length;
    $('.brown').bind("change", function() {
      var listItem = $(this);
      var i = listItem.index(".brown"); //clear all current timeouts
      clearTimeout(timer[i - 1]);
      
      var s = $(this).val();
      //pause for 3 seconds before alert
      timer[i - 1] = setTimeout(function() {
        alert(s);
        timer[i - 1]
      }, 3000);
      //clear all current timeouts
      clearTimeout(timer[i - 1]);

      var s = $(this).val();
      //pause for 3 seconds before alert
      timer[i - 1] = setTimeout(function() {
        alert(s);
      }, 3000);

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply iterate all input fields after you hit the 3 seconds limit? To make sure that your button handles the correct values, you could add a `data-attribute` to your buttons, that point to the field you wish to increase, something like

```
<input type="text" id="first" value="0" />
<button type="button" data-target="first">Increase first</button>
```

Where the button has a link to the input field it has to change, and then you can handle everything with one eventhandler, like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]').forEach( button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

And in handle click, you can then get the attribute, and increase the appropriate field for it

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]').forEach( button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

And in the handle click, you can use the event argument, to retrieve the button that was clicked, what it's target is supposed to be, and then update that field after you have found it

```
function handleClick(e) {
  let source = e.target;
  let target = source.getAttribute('data-target');
  let elem = document.getElementById( target );
  if (!elem) {
    // no elem found
    return;
  }
  elem.value = +elem.value + 1;
  if (handleClick.timer) {
    clearTimeout( handleClick.timer );
  }
  // use a function specific property for the timer
  handleClick.timer = setTimeout( () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( input => {
      if ( parseInt( input.value ) <= 0 ) {
        return;
      }
      alert( input.value );
    });
  }, 3000 );
}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]').forEach( button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});

function handleClick(e) {
  let source = e.target;
  let target = source.getAttribute('data-target');
  let elem = document.getElementById( target );
  if (!elem) {
    // no elem found
    return;
  }
  elem.value = +elem.value + 1;
  if (handleClick.timer) {
   clearTimeout( handleClick.timer );
  }
  handleClick.timer = setTimeout( () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( input => {
      if ( parseInt( input.value ) <= 0 ) {
        return;
      }
      alert( input.value );
    });
  }, 3000 );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first" value="0" />
<button type="button" data-target="first">Increase first</button>
<input type="text" id="second" value="0" />
<button type="button" data-target="second">Increase second</button>
<input type="text" id="third" value="0" />
<button type="button" data-target="third">Increase third</button>
```

I know this is without jQuery, but I didn't really see the need for it